# IndexingError: Too many indexers with Dataframe.loc

Tags: python, pandas

I got this error while I tried to make telegram alarm bot using FinanceDataReader

Here is the code:

```
code = 'KQ11'
df = fdr.DataReader('KR11', '2022-08').reset_index()
df['close_sma3d'] = df['Close'].rolling(3).mean()
df['close_sma5d'] = df['Close'].rolling(5).mean()
df['close_sma10d'] = df['Close'].rolling(10).mean()


print('3,5,10 SMA breakout Signal')

Three_days = 3
Five_days = 5
Ten_days = 10

for i in date_i:

# we cannot calculate the first day and the last day
if i < 1 or i > len(date_list) - Ten_days:
    continue
    
prev_date = date_list[i-1]
now_date = date_list[i]

prev_price = df['Close'].loc[code, prev_date]
now_price = df['Close'].loc[code, now_date]

prev_sma3d = df['close_sma3d'].loc[code, prev_date]
now_sma3d = df['close_sma3d'].loc[code, now_date]

prev_sma5d = df['close_sma5d'].loc[code, prev_date]
now_sma5d = df['close_sma5d'].loc[code, now_date]

prev_sma10d = df['close_sma10d'].loc[code, prev_date]
now_sma10d = df['close_sma10d'].loc[code, now_date]

# 어제는 이평선 밑, 당일은 이평선 위
if now_price > now_sma3d:
    print(f" - {now_date} Signal 발생! now_price {now_price} 3일이동평균 {now_sma3d}")
    
elif now_price > now_sma5d:
    print(f" - {now_date} Signal 발생! now_price {now_price} 5일이동평균 {now_sma5d}")

elif now_price > now_sma10d:
    print(f" - {now_date} Signal 발생! now_price {now_price} 10일이동평균 {now_sma10d}")
```

And here is the code where the error occured:

```
prev_price = df['Close'].loc[code, prev_date]
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
    Date    Close   close_sma3d close_sma5d close_sma10d

9   2022-08-12  831.63  828.016667  829.712 823.267
10  2022-08-16  834.74  832.840000  830.488 825.980
11  2022-08-17  827.42  831.263333  829.242 828.288
12  2022-08-18  826.06  829.406667  830.400 829.358
13  2022-08-19  814.17  822.550000  826.804 828.259
14  2022-08-22  795.87  812.033333  819.652 824.682
15  2022-08-23  783.42  797.820000  809.388 819.938
16  2022-08-24  793.14  790.810000  802.532 815.887
17  2022-08-25  807.37  794.643333  798.794 814.597
18  2022-08-26  802.45  800.986667  796.450 811.627
```

When I `print(prev_date, now_date)`:

```
2022-08-01 00:00:00
2022-08-02 00:00:00
```

it seems really weird cause it's not a form of Multiindex to me

I found that it has no columns even though it's DataFrame. When I `df['Close'].shape` it shows: `(19,)`

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: if error show line `df['Close'].loc[code, prev_date]` then you should check also `code`

Comment: `.shape` is not for checking columns. but number of elements. Check `df.columns`. Besides you check it for single column. And when you get single column `df['Close']` then it gives you `pandas.Series`

Comment: I don't understand why you use `code` in `loc[code, prev_date]` - it should use rather`.loc[row_index(es), column_name(s)]`. If you want to get row with some date then you should use `.loc[ df["Date"] == prev_date ]`

Comment: if you want to compare values from previous row then use `df['Previous Close'] = df['Close'].shift(-1)` to create new column and move all elements up- and this way you will have both values in the same row.

Comment: maybe you should find it without for-loop `df[ df['Close'] > df['close_sma3d'] ]` and later use all values to send messages

Comment: instead of `if i < 1 or i > len(date_list) - Ten_days: continue` you could use slice `for i in date_i[1:-10]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `.loc` with wrong values. It rather need `.loc[ row_indexes, columns_names ]` but you use some strange `code` and value `prev_date`

To select some date it would need

```
df.loc[ df["Date"] == prev_date, 'Close']
```

But you don't need it in some situations.

---

To find all `"Close" >  "close_sma3d"` you can do

```
alert_three_days = df[ df['Close'] > df['close_sma3d'] ]
```

and later iterate this dataframe

```
for index, row in alert_three_days.iterrows():
    print(f" - {row['Date']} Signal 발생! now_price {row['Close']} 3일이동평균 {row['close_sma3d']}")
```

or use `apply()` for this

```
def display(row):
    print(f" - {row['Date']} Signal 발생! now_price {row['Close']} 3일이동평균 {row['close_sma3d']}")

alert_three_days.apply(display, axis=1)
```

---

If you want to compare with previous price then you can use `.shift(1)`

```
df['Previous Close'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
```

and later compare

```
lower_close = df[ df['Previous Close'] > df['Close'] ]
```

and display only selected rows

```
print(lower_close[['Previous Close', 'Close']])
```

---

**BTW:**

When you get single column `df['Close']` then it gives you `pandas.Series` (which don't have columns) and `.shape` shows only number of rows in this `Series`

---

Minimal working code for tests:

```
import FinanceDataReader as fdr

df = fdr.DataReader('KQ11', '2022-08').reset_index()

df['close_sma3d']  = df['Close'].rolling(3).mean()
df['close_sma5d']  = df['Close'].rolling(5).mean()
df['close_sma10d'] = df['Close'].rolling(10).mean()

print('\n--- Close for 2022-08-03 ---\n')

print(df.loc[ df['Date'] == '2022-08-03', 'Close'])

print('\n--- Previous Close > Close ---\n')

df['Previous Close'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
#df['Previous Date']  = df['Date'].shift(1)

lower_close = df[ df['Previous Close'] > df['Close'] ]
print(lower_close[['Previous Close', 'Close', 'Date']])

print('\n--- alert_three_days ---\n')

alert_three_days = df[ df['Close'] > df['close_sma3d'] ]
#print(alert_three_days)

#def display(row):
#    print(f" - {row['Date']} Signal 발생! now_price {row['Close']} 3일이동평균 {row['close_sma3d']}")
#alert_three_days.apply(display, axis=1)

for index, row in alert_three_days.iterrows():
    print(f" - {row['Date']} Signal 발생! now_price {row['Close']} 3일이동평균 {row['close_sma3d']}")
```

Results:

```
--- Close for 2022-08-03 ---

2    815.36
Name: Close, dtype: float64

--- Previous Close > Close ---

    Previous Close   Close       Date
1           807.61  804.34 2022-08-02
5           831.64  830.86 2022-08-08
7           833.65  820.27 2022-08-10
9           832.15  831.63 2022-08-12
11          834.74  827.42 2022-08-17
12          827.42  826.06 2022-08-18
13          826.06  814.17 2022-08-19
14          814.17  795.87 2022-08-22
15          795.87  783.42 2022-08-23
18          807.37  802.45 2022-08-26

--- alert_three_days ---

 - 2022-08-03 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 815.36 3일이동평균 809.1033333333334
 - 2022-08-04 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 825.16 3일이동평균 814.9533333333333
 - 2022-08-05 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 831.64 3일이동평균 824.0533333333333
 - 2022-08-08 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 830.86 3일이동평균 829.2199999999999
 - 2022-08-09 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 833.65 3일이동평균 832.0500000000001
 - 2022-08-11 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 832.15 3일이동평균 828.6899999999999
 - 2022-08-12 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 831.63 3일이동평균 828.0166666666665
 - 2022-08-16 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 834.74 3일이동평균 832.84
 - 2022-08-24 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 793.14 3일이동평균 790.81
 - 2022-08-25 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 807.37 3일이동평균 794.6433333333333
 - 2022-08-26 00:00:00 Signal 발생! now_price 802.45 3일이동평균 800.9866666666667
```

Comment: When I add more `for` below like `for index, row in alert_five_days.iterrows():
    print(f" - {row['Date']} Signal 발생! now_price {row['Close']} 5일이동평균 {row['close_sma5d']}")
for index, row in alert_ten_days.iterrows():
    print(f" - {row['Date']} Signal 발생! now_price {row['Close']} 10일이동평균 {row['close_sma10d']}")` the sequence is messed up. how can I print the result in the order of date?

Comment: if original data are sorted by date then it should display `alert_five_days` in correct way, and later it should display `alert_ten_days` in correct way. If you want to display all alerts together in correct order then first you would have to add column with values `3` to `alert_three_days`, and column with values `5` to `alert_five_days` and column with values `10 to `alert_ten_days`, next merge all these data, next sort them by date and later display them using value `3`, `5`, `10` from added column

Comment: here is my code: `alert_three_days = (df2['Close'] > df2['close_sma3d'] )
alert_five_days = (df2['Close'] > df2['close_sma5d'] )
alert_ten_days = (df2['Close'] > df2['close_sma10d'] )
df2[3] = alert_three_days
df2[5] = alert_five_days
df2[10] = alert_ten_days` But why does df2[3] work and df2[three] doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you means `df2["three"]` with `" "`?